# bash parameter substitution error - Bad substitution

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which is taking a file and converting the `==` to `>=`.  This command works fine from the command line:

```
while read a ; do echo ${a//==/>=} ; done < /opt/scanner/requirements.txt > /tmp/requirements.txt.t ; mv /tmp/requirements.txt.t /opt/scanner/requirements.txt
```

However, when run from inside my script I get:

```
setup.sh: 49: setup.sh: Bad substitution
```

The above one-liner is what is on line 49.  I assume it's because of the `echo ${...}` portion of the command.  My shell script is thinking it's a variable?

Requirements.txt is just a bunch of python packages that I need to change the version restriction on, hence the one-liner:

```
certifi==2018.1.18
chardet==3.0.4
coverage==4.5.1
Django==2.0.4
gitdb2==2.0.3
GitPython==2.1.9
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
netaddr==0.7.19
netifaces==0.10.6
nose==1.3.7
psycopg2==2.7.4
python-nmap==0.6.1
pytz==2018.3
requests==2.18.4
simplejson==3.13.2
smmap2==2.0.3
urllib3==1.22
xml2json==1.1
```

Here is the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage ----
# sh setup.py token environment

# Set environment variable
echo "TOKEN=$1" >> /etc/environment
echo "ENV=$2" >> /etc/environment

# checking for args
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    exit 1
fi

...

while read a ; do echo ${a//==/>=} ; done < /opt/scanner/requirements.txt > /tmp/requirements.txt.t ; mv /tmp/requirements.txt.t /opt/scanner/requirements.txt

# now install the packages
pip3 install -r /opt/scanner/requirements.txt

....

# reboot to finalize changes
reboot
```

How can I edit `requirements.txt` and replace all the `==` with `>=`?  Does my one-line while statement need to be broken out since the parameter expansion is what is killing the script?

Comment: Maybe try double-quoting your variable `"${a//==/>=}"`, otherwise it's unclear what the issue is; maybe provide more information. It looks like you are trying to execute script.sh from script.sh. Also you should probably use `while read -r`, otherwise things can get mangled.

Comment: What does the shebang (#!) line look like in your setup.sh script?  If you use /bin/sh, it is running in POSIX mode which does not support the parameter substitution as you write.  A very old version of bash neither supports it. Try to identify which version of bash is running in your command line and specify it in the shebang line.

Comment: @tshiono I added the bash script.

Comment: `sh yourscript` won't work. You can only use bash syntax if you run your script with `bash yourscript`; the shebang (`#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`) is ignored if started with an explicit (`sh scriptname` or `bash scriptname`) interpreter.

Comment: Also, the "Usage" seems to indicate that the shell script is named setup.py. Please don't use the .py (Python) extension on shell scripts -- it doesn't technically matter, but adds unnecessary confusion. You can use .sh for shell scripts, but it's generally best to not use any extension at all and just let the shebang line control what interpreter is used (i.e. do *not* use `sh scriptname`, since that overrides the shebang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely *nothing* wrong with the sections of the code you've shown that are meant to make the changes. This can be seen if you use the much simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read a ; do echo ${a//==/>=} ; done <inputFile.txt
```

When I run that against your input file, I get what's expected:

```
pax$ ./myScript.sh
certifi>=2018.1.18
chardet>=3.0.4
coverage>=4.5.1
: : :
smmap2>=2.0.3
urllib3>=1.22
xml2json>=1.1
```

A couple of things you *may* want to look at:

- Add `set -x` to the script so that all lines are output before execution - this may indicate where a potential problem lies.
- Within the loop, add the statement `echo ".$a."` to see what the actual input line is.
- Within the loop, add the statement `echo -n "$a" | tr -d '[\-A-Za-z0-9=.]'` to see if there are any unexpected characters (all counts *should* be zero).
- Insert the `( set ; env ) | grep -i bash` statement at the start of the script to make *sure* you're running `bash` (and the correct *version* of `bash`).

That last point is particularly important if you're actually running the script with `sh setup.py ...` as per your comment in the code, since `sh` and `bash` are *not* the same thing. The shebang line normally dictates what shell is used but, if you run it *explicitly* with `sh`, it gets bypassed:

```
pax$ sh myScript.sh
myScript.sh: 2: myScript.sh: Bad substitution
```

In any case, it's probably a better idea to use `sed` for this sort of task:

```
 sed -i 's/==/>=/' inputFile
```

This will edit `inputFile` in-place, making the substitutions on the fly. Then you don't have to worry about any possible vagaries of `bash` or having to move the file yourself after doing the substitution.

Comment: Note the comment in the code saying that the script is intended to be invoked with `sh`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to re-implement `sed` with this loop. Possibly more importantly, use `&&` to make sure you only replace your original file with the new file if `sed` succeeds.

```
orig=/opt/scanner/requirements.txt
tmp=$(mktemp)
if sed 's/==/>=/' "$orig" > "$tmp"; then
  mv -- "$tmp" "$orig"
fi
```

Depending on your `sed`, you can use the `-i` option to modify the original in-place. Check your documentation; both BSD and GNU `sed` support `-i`, but with slightly different usage.